# Inorder successor of BST without parent info

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I was trying to find inorder successor for a node in a BST. And below is my sample code.

```
public TreeNode getInorderSuccesor(TreeNode t)
{

    if(t == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if(t.getRight()!=null)
    {
        t = t.getRight();
        while(t.getLeft()!=null)
        {
            t = t.getLeft();
        }
        return t;
    }
    else
    {
        TreeNode parent = t.getParent();

        while(parent!=null && parent.getLeft() != t)
        {
            t = parent;
            parent = t.getParent();
        }
        return parent;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any condition it will fail. And one more thing if some can share algo/ code/ sudocode for find the inorder successor without parent node. thanks!!!

Comment: You can simply search for the smallest node in the tree that is larger than the current node. Things will be slightly complicated if you have nodes with same value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic logic for the successor function; the predecessor function is similar, but reversed. A recursive function descends the tree searching for the requested key, keeping track of the current tree as the possible successor every time if follows the left sub-tree. If it finds the key, its successor is the minimum element of the right sub-tree, found by chasing left sub-trees until reaching a null node. If the search reaches a null node and hence fails to find the key, the next largest key in the tree is the successor, found in the possible successor that was saved at each recursive call. I recently implemented this algorithm at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2013/02/12/binary-search-tree-in-order-predecessor-and-successor/).

Comment: You don't need to even chase. You only need to keep track of the smallest larger element as you traverse the tree to find some element larger than the current element.

Answer (score 0):

If the nodes in the tree have unique values, then it is quite simple. You just need to find:

- The node with largest number that is smaller than or equal to the value of the node whose successor needs to be determined
- The node with the smallest number that is strictly larger than the value of the node whose successor needs to be determined.

The latter node will be the answer. The first node can be used to check whether the input node is a valid node in the tree.

Pseudo-code:

```
function inOrderSuccessor(val, tree):
    (left, right) = findRange(val, tree.rootnode, null, null)

    if (left.val != val):
        throw Error("No node with specified value")

    return right


function findRange(val, currnode, left, right):
    if (currnode == null):
        return (left, right)

    if (currnode.val <= val):
        return findRange(val, currNode.right, currnode, right)
    else:
        return findRange(val, currNode.right, left, currnode)
```

---

If the nodes in the tree may have duplicate value, the in-order successor is not very well-defined. It is necessary to know when you are given a node, how do you differentiate between different nodes with the same value. Are you given a real reference to the node in the tree?

In the tricky case where you are simply given a reference to a node, and there are other nodes with the same value in the tree, then there are 2 cases:

- Case 1: The node has right subtree, then you only need to find the smallest element in the right subtree.
- Case 2: The node doesn't have right subtree. You need to check reference equality with all the nodes which has the same value. When you have found the node in the tree, traverse upward from the node back to root (you have this in the stack), and find the first node that does a left-turn.